# Код html не проходит валидацию(div + label + input)

Tags: html, валидация

Вот такая вот штука(код ниже). Валидатор матерится, хотя визуально эффект получился :

> Element div not allowed as child of element label in this context

Помогите исправить ошибки, буду благодарен

```css
.cases {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding-top: 52px;
}

.case1, .case2, .case3 {
    float: left;
    margin:10px 46px 0 0;
    width: 270px;
    height: 420px;
    border: 1px solid #EDEDED;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
}

.marker {
    display: block;
    width: 30%;
    height: 2px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #00B533;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

#case1, #case2, #case3 {
    display: none;
}

#case1:checked + .marker {
    opacity: 1;
}

#case1:checked ~ .case-btn, #case2:checked ~ .case-btn, #case3:checked ~ .case-btn {
    background: #00B533;
    color: #fff;
}

/*#case2:checked ~ .case-btn{*/
/*background: #00B533;*/
/*}*/
/*#case3:checked ~ .case-btn{*/
/*background: #00B533;*/
/*}*/

#case2:checked + .marker {
    opacity: 1;
}

#case3:checked + .marker {
    opacity: 1;
}

.case-header {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EDEDED;
    height: 110px;
}

.case-title {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: "Roboto Medium";
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 25px 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.round {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    border: 2px solid #00B533;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;

    font-family: "Roboto Medium";
    font-size: 23px;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

.round p:last-child {
    font-family: "Roboto Light Italic";
    font-size: 10px;
}

.case-description {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 75px;
}

.case-description ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.case-description ul li {
    padding-top: 18px;
}

.case-btn {
    display: block;
    margin: 35px auto 0;
    height: 30px;
    width: 120px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #EDEDED;
    border-radius: 20px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.case-btn:hover {
    background: #00B533;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.case-btn:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="cases">
    <div class="case1">
        <label for="case1">
            <input type="radio" id="case1" name="choice" />
            <div class="marker"></div>
            <div class="case-header">
                <p class="case-title">BLABLABLA</p>
                <div class="round">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="case-description">
                <ul>
                    <li >
                        <p>Some Text</p>
                    </li>
                    <li >
                       Some Text
                    </li>
                    <li >
                       <p>Some Text</p>
                    </li>
                    <li >Some Text</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <button class="case-btn">PURCHASE</button>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Дак написано же в ошибке, что нельзя в `label` - `div` сувать, английским по желтому. Ну, во всяком случае - нельзя по мнению валидатора.

Comment: Так в том-то и загвоздка - как разрулить ситуацию?

Comment: Ну я бы забил, есичесн. Спанами - по моему еще менее валидно, спаны - нужны чтобы в тексте форматирование править, а не блоки отображать.W3C - гласит:
`>A div is placed around a group of block level elements—for example, to wrap a heading plus a list of links to make a navigation menu. A span wraps a group of inline elements or (most usually) plain text`. Так что, можешь например поменять в целом механизм всей конструкции, если тебе так уж нужна полностью валидная страничка.

Comment: А что у вас за бред написан? Label нужен для подписи инпута. В атрибут `for` должен записываться **id** инпута, а Вы подсовываете класс. Зачем-то засовываете `button` туда. Что Ві пітаетесь сделать и зачем Вам `label`?